# How to install Kile in Windows?

Tags: installing, windows, kile

I've been searching how to install Kile in Windows. I've seen many options but none of them works. Any ideas or suggestions? I use Linux and is easy to install and use Kile, but I need it for my job and there are only Windows Os.

Comment: From KDE site about Windows and Mac OS X install: *KDE software on these Operating Systems is in experimental state. Things might, or might not work properly at this point. An installer for KDE applications on Windows is available on  [windows.kde.org](http://windows.kde.org)*.  Other options: A) Install Linux in a HD partition (ok, not in your case).   B) Install Linux in a  virtual machine,  a pendrive or DVD . C) Use another LaTeX editor.

Comment: An excellent video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=g6ez7sbaiWc
Go there ... :)

Comment: Workaround: You could ask your admin to install a real Linux system in a virtual machine like [VirtualBox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VirtualBox) on your windows system. Your system still runs windows, and you have a Linux  for maximum productivity in a window like an application. You can open files in a shared folder from both systems and install Kile and all other TeX tools you miss on windows.

Answer (score 3):

As of Kile 3.0 (beta), now you can either download the [.exe file from the Kile Downloads Page](https://kile.sourceforge.io/download.php) or [install Kile from the Microsoft Store](https://www.microsoft.com/store/productId/9PMBNG78PFK3)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You can use [KDE on Windows](http://windows.kde.org/), as stated in the comment by Fran. It works nicely once you setup the paths correctly (I'm using it on Windows 8.1 and 10).
Obviously you need a separate TeX distribution like MikTeX or TeXlive.

**EDIT**: nowadays you should build it from source by using [`craft`](https://community.kde.org/Guidelines_and_HOWTOs/Build_from_source/Windows).

Comment: One has to keep on mind, that this is more complicate to maintain than a virtual machine with a real Linux. Likely the admin at work will not be very excited to support KDE on Windows at single user desktops.

Answer (score 1):

I've prepared an installer for a recent version of Kile. You can obtain [it there](http://arrowd.name/posts/2017-01-02-kde-installers.html), amongst some other KDE applications.

Comment: Please elaborate on the procedure of installation.

Comment: Run an .exe, that's all. Well, you'd also need a TeX distribution, of course. I used MikTeX and it worked for me flawlessly. Kile has a "System Check" option, which can let you make sure everything is set up correctly.